# what happens to a cron if its not complete and next iteration is due

Tags: php, ubuntu, laravel-5, cron

I know I am asking something and not code related issue but before implementing my cron I wanted to ensure that I know what to expect from the execution.

I have a cron that delivers 125 emails every 2 minutes and I wanted to know if something happens and the cron is not complete by the time the next iteration is due.

sending an average of 125 emails every 2 minutes is very important and I would prefer a solution which will ensure that backlog is cleared whenever possible.

Any advise is highly appreciated.

Comment: are you talking about laravel task scheduler ?, if yes there are ways to handle these conditions

Comment: My app is in Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

Cron launches the specified process, but it does not care what happens to it. Another thread will launch if the timer says so.

The target list should come from a database. When it's time to send the message, make sure it isn't marked sent in the DB already, mark it, and send away. Then it doesn't matter how many parallel threads are running, they won't send duplicate messages.

Comment: so then what happens to the emails that probably did not complete

Comment: Well, that process will keep running and sending emails. You need to make sure that you structure it so that the new process wont send duplicate messages

Answer (score 1):

Cron will trigger your process at specified time interval regardless of whether it finished/completed/failed previous execution. You have to write some logic in your code to check whether an instance of it is already running or not. In shell script, write the below code to check whether the instance of "process.sh" is running or not.

```
    for pid in $(pidof -x process.sh); do
    if [ $pid != $$ ]; then
        echo "[$(date)] : process.sh : Process is already running with PID $pid"
        //do whatever logic u want to do here
    fi
    done
```